# Reorder Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: r, stacked-chart

newbie R coder here. I have a stacked bar chart in base R that I'd like to reorder numerically by question type (Question 1 Pre, Question 1 Post, Question 2 Pre, Question 2 Post, etc.)

It's probably a fairly simple fix but I can't seem to get the reorder function to work. The other questions on reordering don't quite get to my solution. Maybe reorder isn't the right way to go about it?

Attached my graph and base code. Thank you so much! I appreciate your kind help.

[image]

```
if(!require(psych)){install.packages("psych")}
if(!require(likert)){install.packages("likert")}
library(readxl)
setwd("MSSE 507 Capstone Data Analysis/")
read_xls("ProcessDataMSSE.xls")


Data = read_xls("ProcessDataMSSE.xls")

str(Data) # tbl_df, tbl, and data.frame classes

### Change Likert scores to factor and specify levels; factors because numeric values are ordinal

Data <- Data[, c(3:26)] # Get rid of the other columns! (Drop multiple columns) 

Data$`1Pre` <- factor(Data$`1Pre`,
                   levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                   ordered = TRUE)

Data$`1Post` = factor(Data$`1Post`,
                     levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                     ordered = TRUE)

Data$`2Pre` <- factor(Data$`2Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`2Post` = factor(Data$`2Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`3Pre` <- factor(Data$`3Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`3Post` = factor(Data$`3Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`4Pre` <- factor(Data$`4Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`4Post` = factor(Data$`4Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`5Pre` <- factor(Data$`5Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`5Post` = factor(Data$`5Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`6Pre` <- factor(Data$`6Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`6Post` = factor(Data$`6Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`7Pre` <- factor(Data$`7Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`7Post` = factor(Data$`7Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`8Pre` <- factor(Data$`8Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`8Post` = factor(Data$`8Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`9Pre` <- factor(Data$`9Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`9Post` = factor(Data$`9Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`10Pre` <- factor(Data$`10Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`10Post` = factor(Data$`10Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`11Pre` <- factor(Data$`11Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`11Post` = factor(Data$`11Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`12Pre` <- factor(Data$`12Pre`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data$`12Post` = factor(Data$`12Post`,
                      levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"),
                      ordered = TRUE)

Data <- factor(Data,levels=Data[3:26])
Data
### Double check the data frame

library(psych) # Loads psych package

headTail(Data) # Displays last few and first few data

str(Data) # Shows structure of an object (observations and variables, etc.) - in this case, ordinal factors with 4 levels (1 through 4)

summary(Data) # Summary of the number of times you see a data point

Data$`1Pre` # This allows us to check how many data points are really there

str(Data)
### Remove unnecessary objects, removing the data frame in this case (we've converted that data frame into a table with the read.table function above)

library(likert)

Data <- as.data.frame(Data) # Makes the tibble a data frame

likert(Data) # This will give the percentage responses for each level and group

Result = likert(Data)

summary(Result) # This will give the mean and SD 


plot(Result,
     main = "Pre and Post Treatment Percentage Responses",
     ylab="Questions",
     type="bar")
```

Comment: I think you need a grouping variable to represent the 12 questions. The `likert` function has a `grouping` argument which should be able to "group" the Pre/Post pairs for you.

Comment: Can you add the first few lines of `Result`?

Answer (score 0):

I largely agree with @DzimitryM 's solution. It is unclear to me, however whether this really works. In my solution, I need to use the `items` variable of the data.frame, not the data.frame as such. There is some comment in the code below (at the bottom) highlighting this.

Anyway this is the reason I made a working example with executable code.

I am aware of the fact, that it may be improved; my focus was on executability.

```
library(likert)

### mimic some of your data, with 'accepted' naming
Data <- data.frame(
  C01Pre  = as.character(c( rep(1, 10), rep(2, 60), rep(3, 25), rep(4, 5) )), 
  C01Post = as.character(c( rep(1, 25), rep(2, 52), rep(3, 21), rep(4, 2) )),
  C02Pre  = as.character(c( rep(1, 25), rep(2, 68), rep(3,  5), rep(4, 2) )),
  C02Post = as.character(c( rep(1, 30), rep(2, 53), rep(3, 13), rep(4, 4) )),
  C03Pre  = as.character(c( rep(1, 20), rep(2, 52), rep(3, 25), rep(4, 3) )),
  C03Post = as.character(c( rep(1, 20), rep(2, 39), rep(3, 35), rep(4, 6) ))
) 

### coerce to ordered factor 
Data$C01Pre  <- factor(Data$C01Pre,  levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), ordered = TRUE)
Data$C01Post <- factor(Data$C01Post, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), ordered = TRUE)
Data$C02Pre  <- factor(Data$C02Pre,  levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), ordered = TRUE)
Data$C02Post <- factor(Data$C02Post, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), ordered = TRUE)
Data$C03Pre  <- factor(Data$C03Pre,  levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), ordered = TRUE)
Data$C03Post <- factor(Data$C03Post, levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), ordered = TRUE)

Result = likert(Data)

### show the "natural" order when processed by likert()
summary(Result)  
# Item low neutral high mean        sd
# 6 C03Post  59       0   41 2.27 0.8510837
# 1  C01Pre  70       0   30 2.25 0.7017295
# 5  C03Pre  72       0   28 2.11 0.7506899
# 2 C01Post  77       0   23 2.00 0.7385489
# 4 C02Post  83       0   17 1.91 0.7666667
# 3  C02Pre  93       0    7 1.84 0.5983141

plot(Result, 
     group.order = names(Result$items)) ## this is the key!
                                        ## difference with other answer is:
                                        ## names of the "items" variable of the df
                                        ## not the data.frame itself
```

This results in the following graph:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Grouping option can be added to `plot()` in order to get the plot, that is ordered by the column names of the initial dataset:

```
plot(Result,
     group.order = names(Data),
     type="bar")
```